# SMARTYPHP variable not outputting HTML code

Tags: php, html

Hi im using smarty and have declared variables which basically are meant to output the following code.

```
<img src="/images/port.png">
```

However when this is what it outputs `&lt;img src="/images/port.png"&gt;`

The HTML tags are not working and it just shows text.

The code i used in my PHP file is {$configoption.optionname}

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very active, my reputation isn't high enough to comment, but everyone will ask you to see more of your code. If you can put it up I can edit this answer with more helpful info.

Is there a reason you can't just set your smarty variable to the inner string "img src='/images/port.png'" and put content into your template like so 
`< {$imgStr} >` if brackets are giving you trouble?